# How to call a function only for the first time - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Note:** I need to achieve this with pure javascript, I know there is a `.one()` method in jquery to do this, but I need the same output in pure javascript.

**Scenario:** I am trying to call a function when a user scrolls and reaches to the 3/4 part or more of the page, but the problem rises when user reaches that part, *We all know they can't be pixel perfect* so, after the condition is met, the function gets executed per pixel scroll.

I want that to execute only once the condition is met, then add a section at the bottom of the page, and then again user should reach the bottom and the function should get executed only once and so on...

**Snippet:**

```js
var colors = ['skyblue', 'powderblue', 'lightgreen', 'indigo', 'coral'];

var addPage = function() {
  var page = document.createElement('div');
  page.classList.add('page');
  page.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.append(page);
  console.log('added a new page');
}

var scrollAndAdd = function() {
  if (window.scrollY < (window.innerHeight * (3 / 4))) {
    // execute addPage only once for each attempt; it's creating infinite pages
    addPage();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAndAdd);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='page' style='background-color: lightgreen'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: skyblue'></div>
```

Comment: So you will need to remember that you executed your method. Add a global variable and reset when the extra page is added

Comment: Do you only want one page to be added *ever* or is there a condition whereby another can be added again. Should the user first scroll up again, or what is the logic?

Comment: @trincot let's say there are two pages, so the total height of the body should be `200vh` (since 1 page is `100vh`) , assuming user scrolled to `190vh` and trying to scroll even below, then a new page is added, and the total body height is now `300vh`, now user scrolls to `290vh` and more and another page should be added and so on....

Comment: Like @HansKeﬆing says, if you need to remember page state, put that state into global variable(s) to read and update in your function.  Define your state above the function in your script, and give it whatever initial values you want.

Comment: You can make the threshold used to determine if another page should be loaded dynamic. Since page size is fixed (100vh) l. So when you reach 190 update page with new content and add100 to your threshold, and now iff you past that line will a new page be loaded

Comment: Put a `addPage = () => {};` at the end of `addPage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need logic to run the function just once; instead, use a different expression to determine whether to add the page. Once the page is added that same expression should no longer evaluate to true until more scrolling is done.

NB: I also changed a bit the random pick logic.

```js
var colors = ['powderblue', 'lightgreen', 'indigo', 'coral', 'skyblue'];

var addPage = function() {
  var page = document.createElement('div');
  page.classList.add('page');
  // Make sure the same color is not selected twice in sequence:
  var colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length-1));
  var color = colors.splice(colorIndex,1)[0];
  colors.push(color);
  page.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.append(page);
}

var scrollAndAdd = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 10) {
    addPage();
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAndAdd);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='page' style='background-color: lightgreen'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: skyblue'></div>
```

Comment: check this line `var colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.lengt-1));` shouldn't it be `length` there ?

Comment: I meant there is a typo, it should be `length-1` not `lengt-1`

Comment: Ah yes indeed :) Fixed.

Comment: browsing Your answers It's one of my favorite enjoyable activities, here on SO

Comment: Wow, that is a very nice thing to hear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you:

```js
var colors = ['skyblue', 'powderblue', 'lightgreen', 'indigo', 'coral'];

var addPage = function() {
  var page = document.createElement('div');
  page.classList.add('page');
  page.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.append(page);
  console.log('added a new page');
}

var scrollAndAdd = function() {
  var a = document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight * (5 / 4)
  if (window.scrollY > a) {
    addPage();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAndAdd);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='page' style='background-color: lightgreen'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: skyblue'></div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am facing, how is this different than what I provided ?

Comment: @TowkirAhmed, please note that this is different. Look at variable `a`.

Comment: I did, you're right, but the first time it did create too many pages just like mine, will upvote the answer.

Comment: @trincot, thank you thant pointed that my code works correct, moreover, I posted it earlier than you ;)

Comment: Indeed, @qiAlex, but it was a matter of seconds -- good ideas often surface at the same time ;-) I'll give you my vote.

Comment: Thank you @trincot, you answer is better than mine, you also improved random pick logic. I reached my upvote limit today, but I'll upvote your answer later

Answer (score 0):

Well how about curry it up with local flag.

```
var colors = ['skyblue', 'powderblue', 'lightgreen', 'indigo', 'coral'];


const localCurry = function(func, immediateAction) {
  var flag;
  return  function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var callNow = immediateAction && !flag;
    flag = true;
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  }
}


var addPage = localCurry(function() {
  var page = document.createElement('div');
  page.classList.add('page');
  page.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.append(page);
  console.log('added a new page');
}, true);

var scrollAndAdd = function() {
  var a = document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight * (5 / 4)
  if (window.scrollY > a) {
    addPage();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAndAdd);
```

---

Now you do have option to reset the flag based on timer or custom logic.